# How to enable Trace logging in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-logging, .net-core-configuration

I cannot get basice `LogTrace(...)` output in my application. Here's a repro:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Core application using Visual Studio 2017.
2. (Optional) comment out `.UseApplicationInsights()` so the repro is clearer
3. Replace the code in `ValuesController.cs` with this:

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

   namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
   {
       [Route("api/[controller]")]
       public class ValuesController : Controller
       {
           private readonly ILogger<ValuesController> logger;

           public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger)
           {
               this.logger = logger;
           }

           [HttpGet]
           public IEnumerable<string> Get()
           {
               logger.LogError("ERROR!");
               logger.LogWarning("WARN!");
               logger.LogInformation("INFO!");
               logger.LogTrace("TRACE!");
               return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Change `appsettings.Development.json` to this:

   ```
   {
     "Logging": {
       "IncludeScopes": false,
       "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Trace",
         "System": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Information"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. Run and view the Debug output

This leads to:

- Actual output:

  [image: only ERROR, WARN, and INFO]
- Expected output would be the "TRACE!" message as well

I've tried tweaking the values in the `appsettings.json` file as well, but that had no effect either.

Weirdly, changing the value in either file to `"Error"` doesn't do anything either.

#### Bottom Line / Question

What do I need to do to make my injected `ILogger<ValuesController>` respect the logging settings, including `Trace` level?

---

#### Footnote

Here's some of the relevant code that would be auto-generated with the above repro:

`Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

`appsettings.json` default:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up... There will be breaking changes regarding this issue as of 2.0 (credit to @Tseng ). I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **BREAKING CHANGES AS OF 2.0**
> *As Tseng commented below, this answer will become **obsolete as of 2.0** you can find more on this annoucement  here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/238*

---

## Where the problem lies...

Based on your `Configure()` method, I have spotted an issue:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug(); // ⇦ you're not passing the LogLevel!

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

This is the reason why none of your changes to the configuration set in the `appsettings.json` files is not working.

> The default behaviour of `.AddDebug()` without any arguments passed is
> **Adds a debug logger that is enabled for LogLevel.Information or higher.**

If you want to explicitly set it to use a particular minimum LogLevel, then you can pass it directly to the `AddDebug(ILoggerFactory, LogLevel)` method.

```
loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Trace);
```

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.debugloggerfactoryextensions).

---

### Binding it to your configuration.

#### Method 1: Grab the value from the configuration.

```
LogLevel foo = this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging:LogLevel")
    .GetValue<LogLevel>("Default");
loggerFactory.AddDebug(foo);
```

#### Method 2: Use the built-in object for LogLevel

*(Intentionally left out. Obviously it sits snug between these two methods offered.) I would favor one of the extremes than to go halfway)*

#### Method 3: Go Manual (use ConfigurationBinder)

The fancy `ConfigurationBinder`

```
var obj = new MyObject();
ConfigurationBinder.Bind(_configuration.GetSection("Logging:LogLevel"), obj);
```

which will map to an object like

```
public class MyObject
{
    public LogLevel Default { get; set; }
    public LogLevel System { get; set; }
    public LogLevel Microsoft { get; set; }
}
```

so you could then pass:

```
loggerFactory.AddDebug(obj.Default);
```

---

#### Special note about nodes and appsettings.json

Note that the delimiter for the configuration uses `:`.

Example: `"Logging:LogLevel"` will go:

```
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {             ⇦⇦⇦⇦⇦ Here
    "Default": "Debug",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
```

---

#### LogLevel Enum

Just for reference, here are the valid `LogLevel` values:

```
public enum LogLevel
{
    Trace = 0,
    Debug = 1,
    Information = 2,
    Warning = 3,
    Error = 4,
    Critical = 5,
    None = 6,
}
```

*Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LogLevel*

Comment: @Jeroen Did you try `Debug` or `Verbose`.. There is no such option as `Trace`

Comment: There was `Verbose` once, but it was changed some time inbetween ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1 and RC2

Comment: Your changed answer makes sense, and is working. Would you happen to know of a good way to re-use the Configuration section? It seems there is no overload for `AddDebug` that takes one, or is there?

Comment: Might be worth noting, that this gonna change with 2.0 (already in effect in the 2.0 previews): [Breaking Logging changes and new additions](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/238) which will allow configuring all logging providers via appsettings.json

Comment: @Tseng - That's a great note. I appreciate you spotting that.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me. Add it in the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method:

```
services.AddLogging(builder => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried:

```
services.AddLogging(builder => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));
```

> Where the problem lies...

None of those helped me. In my case I had appsettings.Development.json in folder with exe. This file had set Default to Information. That was reason why I could not see Trace logs. This file is hidden in Solution Explorer in visual studio. I had to expand appsettings.json to see this file.

After I changed Information => Trace I could see logs with severity Trace.

Comment: Good catch, now I am embarrassed that I missed that somehow