# SiteMinder SSO not protecting ASP.NET MVC 5 site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, siteminder

This problem may be related to the UrlRoutingModule handling all the routing and bypassing SiteMinder. Any ideas on how may I be able to make SiteMinder's webagent handle the HTTP request before MVC's default request handler?

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- SM Server Config -->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="wa-handler" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%NETE_WA_PATH%\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" 
           resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you share your configuration in web.config ? Is there any error-code ? Did you enable tracing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226554/how-to-enable-trace-logging-in-asp-net-core to see how requests are handeld in your setup ?

Please make sure you also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added my web.config.

Comment: Did use authorization-attributes on your controller-actions ?

Comment: In IIS did you configure windows authentication or anonymous authentication for your website ?  Did you check whether you can see user's name in your webrequest (request.Username) ?

Comment: - No authorization-attributes are currently set on the controllers.
- ISS server is using SiteMinder's web agent as first option to manage auth requests.

Comment: - Non of the default SiteMinder response/request headers are being sent over to the server. Example: 'HTTP_SM_USER' which is the default response header that contains the USER ID is not being populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Resolved: Apparently, for SiteMinder to protect ASP.NET MVC Apps, it must be upgraded to version R12.5 / WebAgent 7 or higher. Just update SiteMinder on your IIS server and it should start working.